# Sass colour lighten function - Using %

Tags: css, sass

As far as I know Sass lighten function works like this:

```
lighten($myColour, 20%);
```

But if you look at this online tool for creating colours:

[enter link description here](http://sassme.arc90.com/)

It creates them as follow without the %:

```
lighten($myColour, 20);
```

Is this OK? Does it make any difference using 20 or 20% ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html), the function [lighten](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method) is said:

```css
lighten($color, $amount)
```

where

> **$amount** (Sass::Script::Value::Number) — The amount to increase the
>   lightness by, between 0% and 100%

**So it can be both.** I tested it in [this CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZbGzZ) and it gave both the same hex value of color.

```
.lighten-number {
  color: lighten(red, 20);
}

.lighten-percentage {
  color: lighten(red, 20%);
}
```